# Generate BibTex citations inside word doc

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc, bibtex

I'm writing up my thesis which partway through I switched to RMarkdown/Zotero for reference managing. My introduction however was written in word, with the 200+ citations made using the very buggy Mendeley-Citomatic add in.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get these citations within the word doc to convert to BibTex keys? I tried updating the citation style with the add on but that hasn't seemed to converted properly i.e `@Johnson-2019`

Once I have the keys in word, I can convert the doc to markdown with pandoc. I previously exported BibTex keys from my mendely db to zotero - Rmarkdown. So the editor should in theory be able to read it from there.

Any help, or other approaches would be much appreciated!

Mari

Answer (score 2):

The latest pandoc versions have support for Zotero citations in Word, and I believe that Mendeley uses the same format. It should therefore be possible to generate a Markdown file by running

```
pandoc --output=intro.md --standalone --from=docx+citations intro.docx
```

which should make it much easier to work with the document. You can also generate a new BibLaTeX from that with

```
pandoc --to=biblatex --output=refs.bib intro.md
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. I get an error reporting that the citations option isn't supported for docx. I downloaded the latest pandoc deb version with no luck either.

Comment: @Mari what do you get if you run `pandoc --version`? The `docx+citations` extension was added in pandoc 2.18, so that's the minimal version you'll need. Get the latest version from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest or use a Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/u/pandoc/.